# Algorithm to generate interval graph

Tags: math, graph

I wonder if there is any algorithm or some easy procedure to generate an [interval graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph)?
I need to generate interval graphs with `n` nodes, where `n` is changing for 1 to, say, 10000.
If it is possible, I need an incidence matrix representation of the graph.
An additional restriction is not to have all these graphs complete.

Thanks everyone in advance!

**==ADDITION==**

Here is an implementation in Java:

```
public Object generate(int numberOfNodes) {
    int listCapacity = numberOfNodes * 2;
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[][] adjacencyMatrix = new int[numberOfNodes][numberOfNodes];
    Integer nodeNumber = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listCapacity; i = i + 2) {
        arr.add(nodeNumber);
        arr.add(nodeNumber);
        nodeNumber++;
    }

    Collections.shuffle(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        for (int j = arr.indexOf(i); j < arr.lastIndexOf(i); j++) {
            adjacencyMatrix[i][arr.get(j)] = 1;
            adjacencyMatrix[arr.get(j)][i] = 1;
        }
        adjacencyMatrix[i][i] = 0;
    }

    return new Graph(adjacencyMatrix);
}
```

Though, in some cases it fails to produce interval graph.

Comment: Any restrictions? A complete graph is an interval graph.

Comment: @JanDvorak, thanks for your responce! Actually, they can be complete graph, but it's not acceptable for me to have all these generated graphs being complete. Will update my question in accordance with your remark, thanks again!

Comment: Any other restrictions? A complete graph with one edge missing is an interval graph. You'll need some more solid requirement, such as "all interval graphs with the given number of nodes must be possible to generate with this algorithm".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way to generate an interval graph with N nodes:

- create an array [1, 1, 2, 2, ... n, n]
- shuffle the array
- create a graph:

  - each node `v_i` corresponds to the pair of occurences of `i` in the shuffled array
  - two nodes `v_i` and `v_j` are connected with an edge iff `i` and `j` are interleaved in the array. That is `i j i j` or `i j j i`, but not `i i j j`. In other words, the intervals `i` and `j` intersect.

This graph is guaranteed to be an interval graph (every node is an interval in the original array), and every graph is possible to create this way.

Comment: Thank you Jan! I tried to implement this algorithm and that worked, at least in most cases :) The thing is that in some cases it fails to produce interval graph. Could you please take a look at my implementation? See edited question.

Comment: @mr.nothing I've reviewed your code and I can see some (performance, readability) issues, but nothing that could cause a bug. Should I post those? Also, could there be a bug in the `Graph` constructor or in the interval-graph-ness checker? I assume they are yours? Can you post the shuffled array that leads to a non-interval graph according to your implementation?

Comment: Thanks one more time, Jan! :) Actually, the only problem I had is that the algorithm presented in this [paper](http://perso.prism.uvsq.fr/~qst/Tarjan/Lex-BFS.pdf) is not working as it should. Now I made some corrections to that algorithm and everything is working as a charm!  
Also about performance issues... It should be better to use LinkedList in the implementation above instead of ArrayList, am I right? And if you have any other thoughts about performance issues in generator, could you, please, share it with me so I can change implementation?